# I want to use value from async function in Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 dynamic data;
```

This is function where I get data for company_name.

```
Future<void> getData() async {
final response = await Provider.of<PostApiService>(context, listen: false)
    .getData(4.toString() + '/service_contracts');

final _getData = GetModel.fromJson(response.body);
print(_getData.company_name);

setState(() => data = _getData.toString());
}
```

Here in Text widget I get null.

```
Text(
      'Adresa je: $data ',
      style: TextStyle(color: AppColors().tabBarText),
                  ),
```

How to get value like in getData func for Text widget?

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `getData()`, and while it is executing, `data` will be null, because all non-late nullable fields in Dart are initialized to null:

```
int? i;
print(i);  // prints null
```

Your `build()` method runs as soon as your widget is inserted into the widget tree, but at this point, your `data` is null, because `getData()` hasn't completed. You can solve this by simply checking in your `build()` method whether `data` is null or not:

```
return data == null ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('Non-null data: $data');
```

Your call to `setState()` inside `getData()` will make sure that the UI updates when this value changes

Comment: I understand, now I get data when call function, but how to get data without call function?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a `FutureBuilder` to wait for a value from an asynchronous method:

```dart
FutureBuilder<YourDataType>(
  future: getData(),
  initialData: null, // You can set a default value here.
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data == null ?
      CircularProgressIndicator() :
      Text('Your data: $data');
  },
)
```

This way you can avoid keeping state for data that you're only requesting once. If `data` is the only state you're currently keeping in your `StatefulWidget` you can simplify everything and just use a `StatelessWidget` instead.